# What is the difference between these two codes to get the date from the timestamp?

Tags: java, hadoop

What is the difference between these two codes? I could get the correct output in HDFS using the first code. output: "hostname  date".
But using the second code I could only get the hostname, the date is not displayed.
Can anyone please explain me the difference between these two Hadoop codes?

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
        //  HostName    TimeStamp                        CPU        %user           
        //  phddn001    240613,20:44        Average:      all       4.05          

    String valueTokens[] = value.toString().split(" ");
    String hostName = valueTokens[0];
    String date = "";
    String timestamp = "";
    for (int cnt = 1; cnt < valueTokens.length; cnt++)
    {
        if (valueTokens[cnt].length() > 0)
        {
            timestamp = valueTokens[cnt];
            break;
        }
    }
    try
    {
        date = timestamp.split(",")[0];
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

---

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
        //      HostName    TimeStamp                          CPU        %user       
        //      phddn001    240613,20:44        Average:        all        4.05        

    String valueTokens[] = value.toString().split(" ");
    String hostName = valueTokens[0];
    String date = "";

    try
    {
        date = valueTokens[1].split(",")[0];
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're splitting on a single space. Your loop is skipping over the empty splits until it finds a non empty string. The second code grabs an empty string, tries to split out a comma, then probably throws an exception that you're not mentioning.

Java's split method accepts a regex, so split on more than one space.

```
value.toString().split("\\s+")
```